# Regex expression - single quote without comma

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to find single quotes that does not have a comma neither right before nor right after it. Also the single quotes should not be the first character or the last character in the string and should have an alphanumeric character on each side

Example "Jane's book" would detect while "'apples','oranges'"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with lookarounds:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])'(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH6uK3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\'(?=[A-Za-z0-9])
```

should give you matches in the languages that support positive lookaheads and positive lookbehinds (JavaScript only supports lookaheads if I remember correctly). I didn't test the above, but I'm not sure you would even need to escape the single quote...

Answer (score 0):

You need your language-appropriate variation of:

```
.+'[^,]+.*
```

`'` finds you a single quote. You generally do not need to escape a single quotation mark.

`[^,]` allows any character but a comma and `+` indicates that you require at least one such character

`.*` says you can have as many of any character as you like, so putting it before and after what you care about says your expression can occur anywhere in the string. `.+` means you must have at least one of any character not a comma.

Note that I'm making some assumptions, like that you'll only have one `'` in the string that you want to find. Also I'm assuming you don't care about `,` except for right after `'`. If that's not true, you need to be more specific about your requirements.